# JavaFX: How to detect CTRL is down, when pressed outside JavaFX application

Tags: javafx

I have a `textArea.setOnDragDropped` method in my JavaFX application.
Within that function, I need to know if CTRL is down.
I can't use a `textArea.setOnKeyPressed` method, because I noticed it only detect key presses when focus is on textarea.

How can I check if a key is down which is pressed outside the focus of the application.

Use case: I open windows explorer. Press CTRL within window explorer and then drag a file to my textarea in the JavaFX application.

```
public class TestApp extends Application {
     final SimpleBooleanProperty isControlDown = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Test CTRL Down");
        final TextArea ta = new TextArea();

        ta.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
            if (e.isControlDown()) {
                System.out.println("Contol is down en property set");
                isControlDown.setValue(true);
            }
        });
        ta.setOnKeyReleased(event -> isControlDown.set(false));

        ta.setOnDragOver(event -> {
            Dragboard db = event.getDragboard();
            if (db.hasFiles()) {
                ta.requestFocus();
                event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.COPY);
            }
        });

        ta.setOnDragDropped(event -> {
            Dragboard db = event.getDragboard();
            boolean success = false;
            if (db.hasFiles()) {
                success = true;
                final String files =
                        db.getFiles().stream().map(File::getAbsolutePath).collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
                if(isControlDown.getValue())
                {
                    ta.appendText(files + " with control down\n");
                    System.out.println("Drop files when contol is down");

                } else {
                    ta.appendText(files + " with NOT control down\n");
                    System.out.println("Drop files when contol is NOT down");
                }
                event.setDropCompleted(success);
                event.consume();
            }
        });

        ScrollPane root = new ScrollPane();
        root.setContent(ta);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 600, 600));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you check if CTRL is pressed in your DropEvent?

Comment: anyway: why do you need to know the keyboard state? typically, it's translated to a copy/move/link by the OS ..

Comment: When ctrl is down I want to show a context menu with options to choose, what to do with the files, otherwise it wil insert the file path into the textarea.

Comment: yeah, the dragEvent doesn't carry the keyboard state. You can it it from a mouse handler: though mouseEvents are delivered to the target only after the drop was done, they are delivered eventually - so you could a) in dragDropped, store the dropped files in some temporary field and complete the dragEvent b) in a mouseHandler check both the files (null or not) and the control key and add depending on both.

Comment: You should just put a menu up as soon as the item has dropped... or tell if you are dragging using the right button or left button of the mouse... and in one case do the default action, and the other produce a menu.

Comment: @trilogy I like your idea about the right button mouse, but still have the same problem. How do I know which mouse button is pressed.

Comment: something like this? `ta.setOnMouseDragged((MouseEvent t) ->
        {
            if (t.isPrimaryButtonDown())
            {
                System.out.println("left");
            }
            if (t.isSecondaryButtonDown())
            {
                System.out.println("right");
            }
        });`

Comment: I would ask another question maybe...